# Priority comparator not working as expected

Tags: java, comparator, priority-queue

```
PriorityQueue<StoreEmail> emails = new PriorityQueue<StoreEmail> (n,
              new Comparator<StoreEmail> () {
                public int compare(StoreEmail a, StoreEmail b) {
                   if(a.urgency != b.urgency){
                       return b.urgency - a.urgency;
                   }
                   else{
                       return a.timestamp - b.timestamp;
                   }
                }
        }
            );


public class StoreEmail
{
    String emailContent;
    int urgency;
    long timestamp;
    StoreEmail(String emailContent, int urgency,long timestamp){
        this.emailContent = emailContent;
        this.urgency = urgency;
        this.timestamp = timestamp;

    }
}
```

Inserting in the queue

```
StoreEmail storeEmail = new StoreEmail(in.next(),in.nextInt(),System.currentTimeMillis());
                emails.add(storeEmail);
```

For above comparator, Inserting following values in the priority queue.

```
store email  value
store email5 4
store email4 4
store email3 4
store email2 4
store email1 4
```

Its giving different result in each run, it means comparator is not working properly, and not able to sort based on time stamp.

Note: Wanted to sort based on email value maintaining FIFO order.
Can somebody help me how to resolve this problem.
Thanks in advance. Wested a lot of time already.

Comment: What datatype is `urgency`?

Comment: This is an integer

Comment: Please add an [mcve] and the expected result

Comment: To compare interger values please use equals method

Comment: Better to use `Integer.compare(first, second)` than subtraction. (Similarly `Long.compare(first, second)` for the timestamps).

Comment: if timestamp is the time at which you added the email (which I'm guessing from your explanation), then you probably have multiple emails with the same timestamp.  That would make sense because the resolution here is milliseconds, and your can probably add more than one entry per millisecond.

Comment: a `java.sql.Timestamp` supports up to microseconds @JoeriHendrickx

Comment: Eventhough having different timestamps, its not able to sort it based on timestamp. Not able to identify, what could be reason of not working.

Comment: @XtremeBaumer if it were a `sql.Timestamp` he wouldn't have been able to use the `-` operator.  So it must be a number somehow.

Comment: @YashodaAgrawal add some print statements to your comparator to see what values it's calculating and what the input is.  Then it should be trivial what the cause of this is.